# Parse Exception in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, typescript, elasticsearch, jhipster

I'm learning about elastic search and I am trying to retrieve data based on a field value in the table.

I have the table (MySQL) "code" which has a field "code_group_id" and existing data in the table.

Using Typescript and Java I would like to retrieve a List of Code objects with a specific code_group_id. I have prepared the following methods in Java:

```
@GetMapping("/_search/codes")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<CodeDTO>> searchCodes(@RequestParam String query, Pageable pageable) {
    log.debug("REST request to search for a page of Codes for query {}", query);
    Page<CodeDTO> page = codeService.search(query, pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generateSearchPaginationHttpHeaders(query, page, "/api/_search/codes");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@GetMapping("/codes/currencies")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<CodeDTO>> getAllByCodeGroupId(Pageable pageable) {
    QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.termQuery("codeGroupId", 3);

    return searchCodes(qb.toString(), pageable);
}
```

According to the ES documentation, the terms query should be the correct choice here as I am looking for a specific query term, so this is supposed to return a response body containing all "code" records that have code_group_id = 3.

However, when I test the GET command on the REST API I get the following exception:

```
2018-04-21 21:32:47.024 ERROR 14961 --- [ XNIO-59 task-5] 
c.i.s.aop.logging.LoggingAspect          : Exception in     ch.ice.swingkasso.service.impl.CodeServiceImpl.search() with cause =     '[code] QueryParsingException[Failed to parse query [{
  "term" : {
    "codeGroupId" : 3
  }
}]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '{
  "term" : {
    "codeGroupId" : 3
  }
}': Encountered " <RANGE_GOOP> "{\n "" at line 1, column 13.
Was expecting one of:
    "]" ...
    "}" ...
    ]; nested: ParseException[Encountered " <RANGE_GOOP> "{\n "" at     line 1, column 13.
Was expecting one of:
    "]" ...
    "}" ...
    ];' and exception = 'all shards failed'

Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: Failed to parse query [{
  "term" : {
    "codeGroupId" : 3
  }
}]
```

Am I overlooking something simple? Thanks for any pointer in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was that the search method re-converted the query into a QueryStringQuery hence the parse Error.

Comment: So what was the fix actually?